# Extended Public Header Block + Point Data Records in LAS 1.4 Point Format Number 6 File

Tags: lidar, las

I've received a couple of LAS 1.4 PDF# 6 files with extended Public Header Block Records + Point Data Records.

I noticed in the example “upgraded” LAS 1.4 file in the URL below, there were extended public header block + point data records.

https://rapidlasso.com/2016/01/10/create-proper-las-1-4-files-with-lastools-for-free/

The extended scan angle in my example file are significantly different than the min/max values in the standard header (assuming the extended_scan_angle is in 32bit int format)

e.g.
  scan_angle_rank   -30         29
..
  extended_scan_angle         -4999   4833

This was the same for the “upgraded” LAS 1.4 file in the URL above

e.g. 
scan_angle_rank -24 24
..
extended_scan_angle -4000 4000

However I can't see these bigger scan angle values in lasinfo, Global Mapper Statistics, ArcGIS Las Dataset Statistics or pdal info.

I was wondering if anyone knew the implications of having these extended records?
Do I ignore these extended records as artefacts of file processing/conversion?

Comment: The extended scan angle is an integer that is multiplied by 0.006 degree at read time to get a value in degree with a resolution of 0.006°. 4000*0.006 = 24. -4999*0.006 = 29.994. Everything seems ok but the software you used to display 4000+ angle values seems to badly interpret the file. Which software are you using?

Comment: These were outputs from two lasinfo reports, for two separate files. 
The scan_angle_rank -30 29 .. extended_scan_angle -4999 4833 was from a lasinfo example from the URL. The second example was from of my files.
Do you have a reference where you found this information by any chance?

Comment: The las specifications http://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/LAS_1_4_r15.pdf lastools does not badly interpret the scan angle but it seems that the choice was to display the raw value in `lasinfo`

Comment: Would this be under the 'Extra Bytes' section (on Page 43), apologies I'm struggling to understand what I'm looking at. Many thanks again.

Comment: Scan Angle page 30

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. Do you happen to know why is it in an extended header is well as the normal header Public Block Record? How can an 'extended_scan_angle' header can appear in the Public Header block when there's no documentation for that specific header?

Comment: There is no extended header. There is one header and Scan Angle is about the payload not about the header. Your question is unclear I don't know how to help you more.